# unable to pxe boot the nodes!

Tags: networking, maas, openstack

I am new to openstack,i am trying to set up a openstack environment,i was going to landscape and then conjure up,but i couldn't get my node to pxe boot,the error i was getting is "cloud init[1379] cannot apply stage final no data source found,likely bad things to come!please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The key here (I think) is that cloud-init can't find the data source.  I am sorry that I have no clue how to fix that, as I have the same problem on my initial PXE boot to become eligible to be listed as a node that is commissionable.

Comment: Did you perchance change the IP of the maas-controller after installation?